# Python module for google search in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-module

I am trying to build an application in GAE using python. I needs to do is give the query received from user and give it to Google search and return the answer in a formatted way to the user. I found lots of questions asked here. But couldn't get a clear answer regarding my requirements. My needs are

Needs to process large number of links. Many Google API described gives only top four links

Which module is best regarding my requirement. Whether I need to go for something like Mechanize, Urllib... I don't know whether they work in GAE. Also found a Google API, but it gives only few results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official library for what you're trying to do, and the Google Terms of Service prohibit using automated tools to 'scrape' search results.